# how can I force a js file download to occur via my Java servlet?

Tags: java, http, servlets

In my organization, all http apps undergo a security check. There are a few headers I need to add to each response via the servlet, that's easy. 
But, I have a new servlet, which returns html code as a response. part of the html is:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src= \""+_pathToScript +"myScript.js\"/>
```

now, the browser gets this response and then generates another GET request for the file. this request is not passing via my servlet and thus I can't add the needed headers to this response.

I tried to change the src value to something like /servlet/MyServlet?GetJS, but the browser doesn't seem to understand that and it doesn't trigger the download.

Any suggestions?

Im running on IBM WebSphere.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use servlet filters.

Comment: Make sure that the URL to the script is mapped to your servlet by configuring the servlet mapping in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor.